# OpenCascade: highlightion and selection styles don't work properly for edges/wires and points

Tags: opencascade

OpenCascade: highlightion and selection styles don't work properly for edges/wires and points, they are highlighted/selected by default color (Quantity_NOC_BLUE/Quantity_NOC_GRAY)
For faces and solids everything works correctly.
What advise to do?
Thanks in advance.

I use this code.

```
Handle(Prs3d_Drawer) highlightStyle = new Prs3d_Drawer();
HighlightStyle->SetColor(Quantity_NOC_YELLOW);
m_Context->SetSelectionStyle(highlightStyle);
m_Context->SetHighlightStyle(highlightStyle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the case here, but if you're trying to highlight subshapes..

`SetSelectionStyle(highlightStyle)` is a shortcut for calling `SetHighlightStyle(Prs3d_TypeOfHighlight_Selected, highlightStyle)`

`SetHighlightStyle(highlightStyle)` is shortcut for calling `SetHighlightStyle(Prs3d_TypeOfHighlight_Dynamic, highlightStyle)`.

As per the docs @ https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/_prs3d___type_of_highlight_8hxx.html

we have 4 interesting values:

- `Prs3d_TypeOfHighlight_Selected`: entire object is selected
- `Prs3d_TypeOfHighlight_Dynamic`: entire object is dynamically highlighted
- `Prs3d_TypeOfHighlight_LocalSelected`: part of the object is selected
- `Prs3d_TypeOfHighlight_LocalDynamic`: part of the object is dynamically highlighted

Therefore if you're trying to change the appearance of subshapes in objects, you need to call

```
Handle(Prs3d_Drawer) highlightStyle = new Prs3d_Drawer();
HighlightStyle->SetColor(Quantity_NOC_YELLOW);
m_Context->SetHighlightStyle(Prs3d_TypeOfHighlight_LocalSelected, highlightStyle);
m_Context->SetHighlightStyle(Prs3d_TypeOfHighlight_LocalDynamic, highlightStyle);
```